# Target popup container

Tags: jquery, popup

I Know this is simple but I cannot get it to work I have a popup that I want to target and set the container to full screen. I am able to target all popups using:

```
 .ui-popup-container{
left:0px !important;
width:100%;
height:100%
}
```

But I want only to target a specific popup and have tried:

```
#complete_pge_faultPop .ui-popup-container{
left:0px !important;
width:100%;
```

height:100%
  }

The targeted popup html:

```
<div data-role="popup" name="faultPop" dsid="faultPop" id="complete_pge_faultPop"
        class="faultlist" data-corners="false" data-dismissible="false" data-overlay-theme="d"
        data-theme="b" data-shadow="false" data-tolerance="4,4,4,4">
            <div class="ui-popup-content-wrapper">
                <!-- faultPop_grd -->
                <div class="complete_pge_faultPop_grd_wrapper" data-wrapper-for="faultPop_grd">
                    <table id="complete_pge_faultPop_grd" class="complete_pge_faultPop_grd" dsid="faultPop_grd"
                    name="faultPop_grd" cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
                        <col style="width:100%;" />
                        <tr class="complete_pge_faultPop_grd_row_0">
                            <!-- mobilegridcell_87 -->
                            <td id="complete_pge_mobilegridcell_87" name="mobilegridcell_87" class="complete_pge_mobilegridcell_87"
                            colspan=1 rowspan=1>
                                <div class="cell-wrapper">
                                    <!-- html_91 -->
                                    <div data-role="appery_html" name="html_91" dsid="html_91" id="complete_pge_html_91"
                                    >
                                        <div style='width:100%;height:100%;padding-top:5;align:center'>
                                            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="false" id="myGroup" style='padding:15px;'>
                                                <legend>
                                                    Load Problem:
                                                </legend>
                                                <input id="radio-choice-1" type="radio" name="radio-choice" value="choice-1" data-theme="a"
                                                style='padding:15px;' />
                                                <label for="radio-choice-1" data-theme="a">
                                                    Damaged Pallet
                                                </label>
                                                <input id="radio-choice-2" type="radio" name="radio-choice" value="choice-2" data-theme="a"
                                                />
                                                <label for="radio-choice-2" data-theme="a">
                                                    Damaged Package
                                                </label>
                                                <input id="radio-choice-3" type="radio" name="radio-choice" value="choice-3" data-theme="a"
                                                />
                                                <label for="radio-choice-3">
                                                    Missing Goods
                                                </label>
                                                <input id="radio-choice-4" type="radio" name="radio-choice" value="choice-4" data-theme="a"
                                                />
                                                <label for="radio-choice-4">
                                                    Damaged Goods
                                                </label>
                                                <input id="radio-choice-5" type="radio" name="radio-choice" value="choice-5" data-theme="a"
                                                />
                                                <label for="radio-choice-5">
                                                    Other
                                                </label>
                                            </fieldset>
                                            <label for="textarea-a" style='align:center;padding-left:10px;word-wrap:wrap;'>
                                                Notes:
                                            </label>
                                            <textarea id="textarea-a" name="textarea" style='padding:5px;' placeholder='Add notes here these will appear on the customer paperwork.'></textarea>
                                            <table style="height: 40px; width: 100%;" border="0" cellpadding="2"
                                            align="center">
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <button id="cancelbtn" data-theme="a" class="complete_pge_mobilebutton_79 ui-link ui-btn ui-btn-b ui-icon-back ui-btn-icon-right ui-btn-inline ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-mini"
                                                            data-corners="true" data-icon="back" data-iconpos="right" x-apple-data-detectors="false"
                                                            data-inline="true" data-mini="true" data-theme="b" tabindex="17">
                                                                Cancel
                                                            </button>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <button id="faultSubbtn" data-theme="a" data-icon="back" class="complete_pge_mobilebutton_79 ui-link ui-btn ui-btn-b ui-icon-back ui-btn-icon-right ui-btn-inline ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-mini"
                                                            data-corners="true" data-iconpos="right" x-apple-data-detectors="false" data-inline="true"
                                                            data-mini="true" tabindex="17">
                                                                Submit
                                                            </button>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
```

How do I target the popup?

Thanks for your suggestions, I have not been able to achieve the desired effect,  I think that the Jquery mobile wrapper probably has something to do with.  I will rethink the approach.

Comment: Where is the element with class ui-popup-container?

Comment: Looks like its jquery mobile, `ui-popup-container` is parent to your popup element, so you cant target it like you want. Can you use just #id selector?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the div with ID #complete_pge_faultPop gets the class you use, so you need a proper CSS cascade:

```
#complete_pge_faultPop.ui-popup-container{
   /* note how there is no space between the two selectors, this means they must be both on the same element */
}
```